# In an excel file I want to rewrite a string from left to write

Tags: excel-2007

In my excel file I have a column containing `123456789` (as an example)
I want to find an excel function to rewrite this string to `987654321`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a new `module` for that. (alt+F11 then right click and 'insert new module')

then you can write something like this in your module :

```
Function Reverse(str As String) As String
    Reverse = StrReverse(str)
End Function
```

with that you will be able to call `=Reverse(A1)` for exemple to reverse the cell text.